# Show <apex:message> for field

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I have a controller extension behind a visualforce page. I add an error to the field ("component id" [according to documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_pages_message.htm#apex_ApexPages_Message_ctor)?!) in a controller extension as follows:

```
ApexPages.Message message = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'hi', 'there', 'xyz');
ApexPages.addMessage(message);
```

Then in visualforce I have:

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Field__c}" id="xyz">
  <apex:selectOption itemValue="stuff" itemLabel="stuff"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</apex:selectRadio>
<apex:message for="xyz" />
```

But the message doesn't appear.

I know the message exists because when I put `<apex:messages />` at the top of thepage I see: `xyz: hi`

How can I put an apex:message on a specific field using `addMessage` in the controller?

ETA: This seems unique to `<apex:selectRadio>`, if I use a regular inputField the associated message *is* rendered.